# How to show the definition of a ML definition in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to follow the Isabelle 2020 documentation implementation.pdf (pp. 55). But I do not understand some ML things such as `\<^binding>` (in terms of what it does; it seems to be a new language outside of SML).

```
ML ‹
  val airspeed_velocity =
    Attrib.setup_config_real \<^binding>‹airspeed_velocity› (K 0.0)
›
```

Following the question [How to show the defintion of functions in Isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556815), I did <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> on the word "binding" in the jEdit/Isabelle PIDE, which leads me to the following definition in `ml_antiquotation.ml`:

```
value_embedded (Binding.make ("binding", ⌂))
  (Scan.lift (Parse.input Args.embedded) >> (ML_Syntax.make_binding o Input.source_content)) #>
```

However, going-to-definition seems to stop working here. I tried to get to further definitions of items such as `Binding.make` and `Scan.lift` to understand how those were defined. But <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> on them no longer works.

I read in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446081/683218) that the Isabelle PIDE can serve as an ML editor.

My question is:

Is there way to let jEdit/Isabelle PIDE jump to definition of items in the ML files after the first jump from a `.thy` file, or in an arbitrary SML file?

Comment: The following Q&A might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59091016/9716869.

Comment: does jumping to Binding.make work in any other file than in ml_antiquotation.ml, like jumping in a theory does not work if it is compiled?